# Why my link anchor does not work in my website?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I have been facing a problem for a few days. On the website I created: https://siros-studio.com, I want to make the captions clickable below the titles of the home page in order to facilitate the user experience.
However my link anchor does not work:

```
<div class="slide-caption" data-slide-caption="1">
    <a data-type="page-transition" href="lestudio.html" style="color: #624a00;">
        <span>QUI SOMMES-NOUS ? <br>NOS SERVICES</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I tried to manage the different z-indexes of the elements of my page but it did not work ...

Have you ever had this type of problem? Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

For #external-caption pointer-events is set to none. You need to change it to "all", but after that there are some further layering issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer  Trethewey!
Indeed, now the texts are clickable but there is a layer problem since the redirect is always made to the same link (the last entered in my html)...